# vagrant 1.8.1 not working

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox

I install vagrant 1.8.1 and virtualbox 5.0.10 but "vagrant up" give me some errors

```
     `<top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/win32/resolv.rb:6:in `
<top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:169:in `<cla
ss:Hosts>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:166:in `<cla
ss:Resolv>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:36:in `<top
(required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/remote_fetche
r.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.
rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
source/rubygems.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
lockfile_parser.rb:87:in `<class:LockfileParser>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
lockfile_parser.rb:14:in `<module:Bundler>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
lockfile_parser.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kern
el_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.
rb:155:in `definition'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.
rb:123:in `setup'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:7
1:in `<main>'
```

where is the mistake please

Comment: what box are you trying to run?

Comment: OS? I suspect windows... have you ever managed to run something in your vagrant?

Comment: is the trace even completed ? the very first line should tell about missing gem

Answer (score -1):

This will install stable ruby

```
sudo apt-get update -y
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
source /home/vagrant/.rvm/scripts/rvm
apt-get upgrade -y
ruby -v
```